# how to compile laravel vite and vue js code

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vite

I want to know how to compile vue components with laravel vite
Iknow that to compiling code with laravel mix i use `npm run watch`, but this current application, that i worked on it, it use laravel vite not mix.
I tried to modifying code and upload it to the server, the content file change but the nothing was changed on application

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview",
    "test": "eslint ./resources/scripts --ext .js,.vue"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rvxlab/tailwind-plugin-ios-full-height": "^1.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^1.10.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.22",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "eslint": "^7.27.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-beta.4",
    "laravel-vite": "^0.0.7",
    "postcss": "^8.2.13",
    "prettier": "^2.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.12",
    "tailwind-scrollbar": "^1.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.7",
    "vite": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/vue": "^1.4.0",
    "@heroicons/vue": "^1.0.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.3",
    "@tiptap/core": "^2.0.0-beta.85",
    "@tiptap/starter-kit": "^2.0.0-beta.81",
    "@tiptap/vue-3": "^2.0.0-beta.38",
    "@vuelidate/components": "^1.1.12",
    "@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.32",
    "@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.0-alpha.25",
    "@vueuse/core": "^6.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "guid": "0.0.12",
    "lodash": "^4.17.13",
    "maska": "^1.4.6",
    "mini-svg-data-uri": "^1.3.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "pinia": "^2.0.4",
    "postcss-inset": "^1.0.0",
    "v-money3": "^3.13.5",
    "v-tooltip": "^4.0.0-alpha.1",
    "vue": "^3.2.0-beta.5",
    "vue-flatpickr-component": "^9.0.3",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.1.7",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.8",
    "vue3-colorpicker": "^1.0.5",
    "vuedraggable": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'laravel-vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        watch: {
            ignored: ['**/.env/**'],
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "vue-i18n": "vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.cjs.js"
        }
    }
}).withPlugins(
    vue
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your postcode `package.json`

The available command for your application is

```
"dev": "vite",
"build": "vite build",
"serve": "vite preview",
"test": "eslint ./resources/scripts --ext .js,.vue"
```

When you run `npm run dev` it will compile the code and start the development server on localhost.

`npm run build` will create the production build for deployment on the live server.

`npm run serve` will create the production build and start the server on localhost for you to preview it.

Comment: but I work on server directly via sftp extention, what i whould add or change ?

Comment: if your server is capable enough then you can create a build using the terminal. but I suggest to do code and test in local machine and just deployed build code in server

Comment: I tried `npm run build ` but  it gives an error : `You must supply options.input to rollup`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you configured your vite build right, you can add maybe an addition `script` e.g:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "vite",
  "build": "vite build",
  "preview": "vite preview --port 5050",
  "watch": "vite build --watch",
},
```